# Como resolver o problema da variável c - capacidade da string, começar a crescer exponencialmente apartir do 3º ciclo

Tags: c, string, funções, for

Estou a ter um problema, aqui com um programa que tem como objetivo, ser uma rotina de entrada de dados, o problema em questão, é a variavel c que vai a funçao capac para pedir ao user a capacidade máxima da string, ao chegar ao 3º ciclo do for ela começa a crescer sabe lá deus pq, tornando o meu for, em algo inutilizável.

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>


int func_carac(int *car) //funcao que pesca os caracters intrudozidos pelo user
{
  int caracter;

  printf("\nDigite o caracter que quiser: \n");
  caracter = getche();

  *car = caracter;
  return *car;
}

//________________________________________________________\\

int func_capac(int *cap) //funcao para pedir ao user a quantidade de caracteres
{
  int quant;

  printf("\nDetermine a capacidade mï¿½xima de caracteres que quer escrever: ");
  scanf("%d",&quant);

  *cap = quant;

  return *cap;
}

int main()
{
  int car, pos, c, total;
  char vetor[] = {'\0'};

  func_capac(&c);

  total = c + 1;
  vetor[total];
  vetor[total] = '\0';
  printf("%i", c);

  for(pos = 0; pos < c; pos++)
   {
    func_carac(&car);
    if((car >= 97) && (car <= 122) || (car == 32))
     {
      printf("\n%c - Tabela ASCII, %d \n",car ,car);
      printf("%i", c);
    
      vetor[pos] = (char) car;
     }
    else if(car == 8)
     {
      printf("Removeu com sucesso o caracter anterior.");
      pos = pos-2;
     }
    else
     {
      pos--;
     }
   }
  printf("Frase: %s\n",vetor);
}```
Se alguem me pudesse ajudar ficava agradecido
````

Answer (score 1):

Seu programa tem muitos problemas. Acho que algumas coisas não funcionam do modo como imagina. Vou tentar reescrever o programa e mostrar alguns exemplos, porque acho que pode ajudar outros.

Vou tentar não mudar a estrutura e deixar tudo como escreveu.

#### os headers e a primeira função

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int func_carac(int *car) //funcao que pesca os caracters intrudozidos pelo user
{
  int caracter;

  printf("\nDigite o caracter que quiser: \n");
  caracter = getche();

  *car = caracter;
  return *car;
}
```

Acho que nada usa de `string.h` ou de `stdlib.h`. Evite incluir headers desnecessários.

`conio.h`  por outro lado é algo dos anos 80 e acho que deve simplesmente esquecer isso. Não é portável, nada tem de importante lá dentro, não faz parte da linguagem e isso tem mais de 40 anos. Vem de uma biblioteca da Borland usada nos anos 80 num produto chamado Turbo C, pouco depois do Turbo Pascal que tinha algo semelhante.

Em relação à função:

```
    int func_carac(int *car) //funcao que pesca os caracteres introduzidos pelo user
```

Qual o propósito de passar um parâmetro, um ponteiro, se a função vai retornar um `int`?
E porque retornar um `int` se vai ler uma letra?

Retorne apenas a letra:

```
char        func_carac() //funcao que pesca os caracteres introduzidos pelo user
```

e assim pode usar em uma expressão, como em

```
    char car = func_carac();
```

ao invés de

```
func_carac(&car);
```

- `main()` deve ser a primeira função de seu programa. Ou deixada em um arquivo separado. É o mais legível e o mais prático: assim pode escrever vários testes para suas funções e distribuir para usar em outros programas. É pra isso que elas são escritas afinal. Use protótipos. E um arquivo .h se possível.

#### `func_capac()`

Aqui tem o mesmo problema: o objetivo é só retornar um número, um tamanho. Pode retornar um valor negativo, assim da uma chance do cara desistir, ou retornar o tamanho máximo do vetor. Mas você mais uma vez usa um ponteiro. Se puder, evite usar acentos. Só vai dar problema e pouco acrescenta. Prefira

```
    int func_capac(); //funcao para pedir ao user a quantidade de caracteres
```

e assim ao invés de escrever

```
  int capacicade = func_capac(&c);
```

pode escrever algo mais legível, como

```
  int capacidade = func_capac();
```

#### o vetor

```
  char vetor[] = {'\0'};
```

- pra que escrever '\0' para um zero? zero é zero. Escreva `0`.
- pra que --- hipoteticamente --- inicializar o vetor se vai ler os elementos a seguir?
- em C é preciso dar uma dimensão fixa, constante, para o vetor na declaração. E você estabeleceu como [1] ao declarar como fez. O que escreveu é o equivalente a

`char vetor[1] = 0`;

Mas o que você quer na verdade é criar um vetor do tamanho especificado pelo usuário. A maneira comum de fazer isso é usar `malloc()` ou `calloc()` e passar o tamanho. E o tamanho veio da função `func_capac()`.
A diferença entre `calloc()` e `malloc()` é que a segunda inicializa a área alocada com zeros, que foi o que você tentou fazer. Mas é pouco útil nesse caso: como eu disse, você vai ler valores em cima desses então não há razão para perder tempo inicializando tudo.
Você pode escrever simplesmente

```
  int capacidade =  func_capac();
  char* vetor =     malloc(capacidade);
```

E aí ler os valores.

```
  for(pos = 0; pos < c; pos++)
   {
    func_carac(&car);
    if((car >= 97) && (car <= 122) || (car == 32))
     {
```

- Prefira o simples: 'a' para 97 e 'z' para 122. Para o compilador tanto faz. E para quem está lendo o programa é melhor o simples: a letra. Ninguém vai achar seu programa melhor porque você sabe os códigos das letras na tabela ASCII. Até o programa rodar em um ambiente que não use eventualmente ASCII :) e onde seu programa vai parar de funcionar.
- NUNCA deixe as variáveis de controle de um loop fora dele a menos que a lógica assim o peça. Levou muitos anos para corrigirem isso no C, mas foi feito ainda nos anos 80. Escreva

```
    for(int pos = 0; pos < c; pos++)
    {   // preenche o vetor
        vetor[pos] = func_carac();
        if(
            ((vetor[pos] >= 'a') && (vetor[pos] <= 'z')) || 
            (vetor[pos] == ` `)
        )   printf("\nvetor[%d/%d] = `%c` - Tabela ASCII = %d \n",
                pos, capacidade, vetor[pos], vetor[pos]);
    };  // for()
```

Sobre essa parte:

```
    else if(car == 8)
     {
      printf("Removeu com sucesso o caracter anterior.");
      pos = pos-2;
     }
    else
     {
      pos--;
     }
   }
```

Entenda que isso é bem problemático: `pos` é uma variável global. E ainda é a variável de controle do loop! Então você está simplesmente reconsiderando o incremento na subtração. E o `else` garante isso. Então não é o certo... O simples é

- nãp usar `pos++` no `for`
- só incrementar `pos` se o valor não for BACKSPACE. E mais uma vez recomendo escrever algo como backspace e não 8. Ninguém vai se impressionar por você saber o código de BACKSPACE mas muitos não vão gostar de ficar interpretando o programa lendo 8, 32, 97 e 122. Pode ser considerado pedante. Mas é menos legível por certo... Eis o que tentou escrever:

```
#define BACKSPACE 8
// ...
    for(int pos = 0; pos < capacidade;)
    {
        func_carac(&car);
        if((car >= 97) && (car <= 122) || (car == ` `))
        {
            // ...
        }
        if(car != BACKSPACE) ++pos;
     }
```

#### a questão de ler o backspace

Em geral a entrada via terminal é feita num modo chamado "*cooked mode*" em Unix e descendentes ou "*line input*" no Windows e desde o DOS. E isso quer dizer, entre outras coisas, que os caracteres aparecem na tela conforme você digita, e a função só retorna e sempre retorna ao ler um ENTER, o tal newline, `'\n'`. E o usuário pode usar backspace para apagar o que foi digitado.

Só que uma série de backspaces pode ir apagando até não sobrar anda na linha, e mesmo assim o cara pode continuar digitando backspaces por toda a eternidade.
Em seu programa isso não funciona: apenas trataria um backspace por vez e teria que ter uma letra depois.
`getche()`  de conio.h pode retornar 8 para BACKSPACE mas não vai recriar o comportamento do sistema. Faltaria voltar o cursor, apagar a letra e tal...
Não parece ser uma boa razão para usar essa função ancestral para fazer uma parte do que o sistema já faz.
Se quer mesmo recriar esse comportamento use o clássico:

- desligue echo e line input, usando `ioctl()` no Unix ou `SetConsoleMode()` no Windows.
- leia as teclas e vá editando o buffer conforme os dados entram
- isso inclui mover o cursor para o lugar certo e ir apagando conforme entrem BACKSPACES

#### o programa reescrito

Sem a parte de tratar os BACKSPACE, porque não é assim que funciona e não é isso que estou  tentado mostrar (como recriar LINE INPUT). Se é isso mesmo que quer escreva de volta ou poste outra pergunta e mostro um exemplo para Windows ou Linux quando der tempo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int         func_capac();
char        func_carac();

int main(void)
{
    int capacidade =  func_capac();
    char* vetor =     malloc(capacidade);

    for(int pos = 0; pos < capacidade; pos++)
    {   // preenche o vetor
        vetor[pos] = func_carac();
        if(
            ((vetor[pos] >= 'a') && (vetor[pos] <= 'z')) || 
            (vetor[pos] == ` `)
        )   printf("\nvetor[%d/%d] = `%c` - Tabela ASCII = %d \n",
                pos, capacidade, vetor[pos], vetor[pos]);
    };  // for()
    printf("Frase: \"%s\"\n",vetor);
    free(vetor);
};  // main()


int func_capac() //funcao para pedir ao user a quantidade de caracteres
{
    int quant;
    printf("\nDetermine a capacidade maxima de caracteres que quer escrever: ");
    int res = scanf("%d", &quant);
    fgetc(stdin); // le o resto da linha
    if ( res != 1 ) return -1; // nao leu nada
    if ( quant < 1 ) return -2; // tem que ser positivo
    return quant;
}


char        func_carac() //funcao que pesca os caracters introduzidos pelo user
{
    printf("\nDigite o caracter que quiser: \n");
    char car = fgetc(stdin); // de stdio.h
    fgetc(stdin); // le o '\n'
    return car; // de stdio.h
};
```

#### uma execução disso

```
tst$ gcc -Wall -o outro -O3 -Wall -std=c17 outro.c
tst$ ./outro

Determine a capacidade maxima de caracteres que quer escrever: 4

Digite o caracter que quiser: 
1

Digite o caracter que quiser: 
2

Digite o caracter que quiser: 
3

Digite o caracter que quiser: 
4
Frase: "1234"
```

Comment: Agradeço proposta de resposta, mas este é o exercício que me foi pedido na universidade, é sobre tabela ASCII, logo, sim o professor vai "achar o meu programa melhor porque sei os códigos das letras na tabela ASCII", entre outras coisas que eu fiz propositalmente por ser pedido, peço desculpa se acho um código mal feito, mas eu já corrigi o meu erro que era o ciclo não funcionar devido a string. 

Espero que tenha um resto de bom dia.

E já agora estude mais, porque todos precisamos ;)

Comment: :) Bom que corrigiu tudo. Por certo usar números ao invés das letras para designar as letras não era de fato o problema. Mas imagino que tenha revisto a declaração de `vetor`, a alocação de memória e os argumentos das funções. E notado que no máximo um backspace vai ser tratado por vez no loop do modo como escreveu. Abraço